# Create a column in one attribute table based on a column in another attribute

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table

In QGIS, I have a river shapefile that does not include the basin that is in. I have a separate shapefile that does. Is there a way to get that river shapefile to have a new column of basin data in the attribute table based on the separate shapefile's basin? The data in the separate shapefile may not have the same length as the shapefile in the river shapefile and the only way to link the two shapefiles is based on geographic location.

Answer (score 1):

A spatial join is the action you are looking to perform.

In QGIS this can be performed by using 'Join attributes by location' under Processing > Vector General

Answer (score 0):

If your river shapefile doesn't "end" at the basin-border, you may try `intersect`. This divides a shapefile by another and attaches all/chosen attributes of the second shapefile to the first, divided one.